# libgdx audio lag (less than one second, but noticeable) ... Java / LibGDX

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

I have a medium-sized Java / Libgdx application where all of the Sound clips are slightly delayed when played.  Each of these is loaded with the asset manager in the beginning of the application.  They range in size from 7 to 220 kb.  I tried both decreasing and increasing the size of the files.  I tried both wav and ogg.  Two classes handle the operations related to sounds, AssetMgr and Sounds.  After loading the sounds via the asset manager, the Sounds class activities occur.  If necessary, I can post links to the classes in GitHub.  As far as memory consumption, while otherwise a fairly small game, some pretty large graphics exist, but they total well under 1 mb.  I am loading pixel maps for a couple of the smaller ones.

> Queueing sounds for loading with asset manager...
>   // elements = List of sounds to load.  Must include full path and extension.  Example:  "assets\beep.wav", "assets\click.wav".
>       public void queueSounds(String ... elements)
>       {

```
    // The function adds the passed sounds to the asset manager for future loading.

    // Loop through each element passed to function.
    for (String element : elements)
    {
        // Add current element in loop to queue.
        manager.load(element, Sound.class);
    }

}
```

> Copying references to hash maps in the Sounds class (please ignore the music piece)...

```
    String filePath; // (Relative) path to sound or music -- used as key in asset manager.
    String musicKey; // Key to use with hash map -- one of the MusicEnum values, as a String.
    String soundKey; // Key to use with hash map -- one of the SoundEnum values, as a String.

    // Initialize the hash maps.
    soundMap = new HashMap<>();
    musicMap = new HashMap<>();

    // Populate hash map for sounds.

    // Loop through sound enumerations.
    for (HeroineEnum.SoundEnum soundEnum : HeroineEnum.SoundEnum.values())

    {

        // Get key / file path for sound.
        filePath = soundEnum.getValue_FilePath();

        // Get enumerated value for the sound, as a String.
        soundKey = soundEnum.toString();

        // Add sound related to current enumeration to hash map.
        soundMap.put(soundKey, hdg.getAssetMgr().manager.get(filePath));

    }
```

> Playing a sound...

```
// whichSound = Name of sound to play.  Corresponds to one of the enumerated 
values in SoundEnum.
public void playSound(HeroineEnum.SoundEnum whichSound)
{

    // The function plays the passed sound -- matching the enumerated key value to the key in the hash map.

    // Play sound.
    soundMap.get(whichSound.toString()).play(audioVolume);

}
```

Comment: Where is this happening? In desktop app, when started on real device or in emulator maybe? I've developed few LibGDX apps, but this never happen to me. I has sound issues at app start or when my frame drawing takes too long, but never beside that.

Comment: Environment:  Desktop via NetBeans.  No Gradle.  The lags occur well after the app starts.  The only image drawing occurring would be in the update event, which is minimal.  The images that exist are quite large, though.  A region is cut out of a texture that is originally 3840 x 1440 when the application originally starts.  The region is 960 x 720.  Up to eight of these regions are displayed.  The future plan is to reduce the region to the minimum necessary size. All cropping occurs when the app starts, though (asset manager).

Comment: Can you comment out temporary those drawing calls and check will lag still appear?